# How to do the same thing with prototype?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

```
$(function() {
    $('#parent').change(function() {
        $.get('get_son.php', {province: $('#parent').val()}, function(result){
            if(result){
                var html = '';
                for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                    html += '<option value="' + result[i].id + '">' + result[i].name + '</option>';
                };
                $('#son')
                    .find('option:gt(0)')
                    .remove()
                    .end()
                    .append(html)
                    .val(-1);
                }
        });
    });
});
```

The above is written in jQuery,

how to do the same thing with prototype?

Answer (score 3):

To start you'll need to make the following changes:

- Replace your calls of **$('#foo')** with **[$](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/)('foo')**.
- Replace the **change(function() {** call to **[observe](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/observe/)('change', function() {**.
- The **get** call will have to be replaces with a **[Ajax.Request](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Request/)** call.
- The **val** calls can be replaced with **[getValue](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/Element/prototype/getValue/)**.
- The **find** calls can be replaced with **[select](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/select/)**.
- The **remove** calls can be replaced with **[remove](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/remove/)**.
- The **append** calls can be replaced with **[insert](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/insert/)**.

I don't think there is a equivalent to **end** so that piece may have to be reworked to save the  results of **$('#son')** and the **find** in variables and apply each operation separately.

Comment: How do you select by `.class` with prototype?

Comment: How do you find `$('#id .class')` then?

Comment: $$ in prototype uses a CSS selector just like $ in JQuery so it is like this... `$$('#id .class')`

Comment: An alternative to `$$('#id .class')` is `$('id').select('.class')`.  [RTM](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/)

Comment: IMO prototype can't interpret such selector as `'option:gt(0)'`